# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si existe un dato en un fichero o archivo txt?

Tags: java

Quiero saber cómo puedo comprobar que un dato ya existe en una línea. 
Probé utilizando un bucle While, pero da la casualidad que el mismo hace que no se imprima nada sobre el fichero. Acá dejo el método para que me puedan decir que estoy haciendo mal. Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
 public void ingresar(String nombreArchivo,String nombre, String ID, String cedula) {

 String temporal="";
    try{
        FileWriter escritura = new FileWriter(nombreArchivo + ".txt", true);
        BufferedWriter escrituraLinea = new BufferedWriter(escritura);
        PrintWriter imprimir = new PrintWriter(escrituraLinea);
        FileReader lector = new FileReader(nombreArchivo + ".txt");
        BufferedReader lectorLinea = new BufferedReader(lector);
        while((temporal=lectorLinea.readLine())!=null){
            if(temporal.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)){



        imprimir.println(ID+"/"+nombre+"/"+cedula);
        imprimir.flush();

    }else{
            System.err.println("iguales");
            }


    }} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo crear el archivo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas crear una y otra vez el archivo, ya que esto puede ocasionar problemas, puedes verificar si existe me diante el método `.exists()`, si no existe lo creas:

```
 File f = new File(nombreArchivo + ".txt");
 if(f.exists()){
        //Archivo existe.
 }else{
        //Archivo NO existe, lo crea.
        FileWriter escritura = new FileWriter(nombreArchivo + ".txt", true);
 }
```

Recuerda que en este punto el archivo esta vacio por lo cual no encontrará coincidencia, puedes editarlo manualmente para agregar información.

También puedes hacer uso del método `.contains()` para encontrar un coincidencia del ID en cada linea del archivo y de esta forma imprimir si existe:

```
    FileReader lector = new FileReader(nombreArchivo + ".txt");
    BufferedReader lectorLinea = new BufferedReader(lector);
    while ((temporal = lectorLinea.readLine()) != null) {

        if (temporal.contains(ID)) {

             System.out.println("Existe: " + ID + "/" + nombre + "/" + cedula);

        } else {
            System.err.println("no existe..");
        }
    }
```

Este sería el método con la modificación:

```
   public static void ingresar(String nombreArchivo, String nombre, String ID, String cedula) {

        String temporal = "";
        try {

            File f = new File(nombreArchivo + ".txt");
            if(f.exists()){
                //Archivo existe.
            }else{
                //Archivo NO existe, lo crea.
                FileWriter escritura = new FileWriter(nombreArchivo + ".txt", true);
            }

            //BufferedWriter escrituraLinea = new BufferedWriter(escritura);
            //PrintWriter imprimir = new PrintWriter(escrituraLinea);
            FileReader lector = new FileReader(nombreArchivo + ".txt");
            BufferedReader lectorLinea = new BufferedReader(lector);
            while ((temporal = lectorLinea.readLine()) != null) {
               // if (temporal.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)) {
                if (temporal.contains(ID)) {

                     System.out.println("Existe: " + ID + "/" + nombre + "/" + cedula);
                    //imprimir.println(ID + "/" + nombre + "/" + cedula);
                    //imprimir.flush();

                } else {
                    System.err.println("no existe..");
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo crear el archivo");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno modifique tu código ligeramente para que puedas realizar el equals con los datos que necesitas, en este caso si los datos que ingresas no existen entonces se adiciona esa linea y si no solo muestra el mensaje de que ya existe.

Imagino que eso es o que querias hacer, la linea que pusiste `if(temporal.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)){` del if no realizaria la comparacón ya que la linea cuenta con los tres campos.

```
public static void ingresar(String nombreArchivo,String nombre, String ID, String cedula) {
    String temporal="";
    try{
        FileWriter escritura = new FileWriter(nombreArchivo + ".txt", true);
        BufferedWriter escrituraLinea = new BufferedWriter(escritura);
        PrintWriter imprimir = new PrintWriter(escrituraLinea);

        FileReader lector = new FileReader(nombreArchivo + ".txt");
        BufferedReader lectorLinea = new BufferedReader(lector);

        boolean exist = false; // Controla si existe la linea
        String nuevosDatos = ID+"/"+nombre+"/"+cedula;
        while((temporal = lectorLinea.readLine()) != null){
            if(temporal.equalsIgnoreCase(nuevosDatos)) {// Verifica que la linea exista
                exist = true;
                break; // Si se encuentra al menos una coinciencia detenemos la iteración y cambiamos el estado de exist
            }
        }
        if (!exist) { // Si no existe agregamos la linea
            imprimir.println(nuevosDatos);
            imprimir.flush();
        }
        else
            System.err.println("Existe un dato igual");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo crear el archivo");
    }
}
```

Ahora bien si solo necesitas validar por **ID** solo tendrias que cambiar la linea del `if` utilizando un `indexOf(ID) != -1` o tambien otros tipos de comparadores.

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)